# Set Content-Type header in CakePHP with JSON

Tags: php, http, cakephp, header

I need to set `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` in a data view from CakePHP. I've already tried to set `$this->response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');` but that doesn't change anything. It still just output `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: is your application on utf8? via core.php? then it should do that by default.

Comment: Yes it is set to `'App.encoding', 'UTF-8'`.

Comment: I just found out that every normal view send the header. The JSON view is the only view that doesn't send the correct header.

Comment: Why are you setting it in the view and not in the controller which you have to pass anyway?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. I don't set a header in the view. The header is set by default in every normal view except the JSON view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its in the code (CakeResponse, line 447):

```
if (strpos($this->_contentType, 'text/') === 0) {
    $this->header('Content-Type', "{$this->_contentType}; charset={$this->_charset}");
} else {
    $this->header('Content-Type', "{$this->_contentType}");
}
```

so only for "text/..." the charset will be appended.
I dont know why, though...

Comment: why looking for a workaround? either googling and finding out that other types have a "right" to also be appended with the charset and making this an official cakephp bug - or realizing that cakephp actually sets the headers properly according to the HTTP spec. both is possible.

Comment: PS: My googling revealed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean => "redundancy" for json anyway. about other types I don't know.

Comment: for clarification: "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" has been added to the core as fix for this in the current master branch: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/9b479958f613e2ce1d290f26d246e76313e821f2 - the issue is officially solved

Comment: It was, back then in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I had this same problem just last night. It seems that UTF-8 is the default JSON encoding and that's probably why the header isn't sent by Cake (but I couldn't find reference to this decision either way).

Solution for me was to use a php's `json_decode()` -- it should decode the string properly.  I had lots of French accents showing up as java/C unicode, e.g. `\u00E9` and thought it was a header problem.  But after running the string through `json_decode()` the accented characters all showed correctly.

Marks' link the comments has good info too.

Answer (score 0):

for this you can place this in the controller / function:

```
json_encode($updown_rs);
```

and in the view file (views/check_json):

```
var json_object = $.parseJSON(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

application/json doesn't have a charset parameter. There's no point in trying to set one. See http://rfc7159.net/rfc7159#ianacons.

Answer (score 0):

I´m using cake 2.10.11 and just used this code in the json layout:

```
$this->response->charset('utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `$this->RequestHandler->ext = 'json';` in your beforefilter method

check out the following example

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->RequestHandler->ext = 'json';
}

public function index()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $output = array(
      array('value' =>'first value'),
      array('value' =>'second value'),
    );
    $json = json_encode($output);
    $this->response->body($json);
}
```