# setting content-type overwriting httpbody?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm having a weird issue calling an API from my ios app. I create a post request

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                requestWithURL:url
                                   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                               timeoutInterval:5.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

I then create json to send to the request and add it to the body of the request like so:

```
[request setHTTPBody:encodedData];
```

Finally, I am adding a few cookies which I then set with:

```
NSArray* cookieArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: sessionCookie, uidCookie, vidCookie, nil];
NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookieArray];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
```

This all works fine. However, since I am sending json I'm trying to be good and also set the content type with this line of code:

```
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
```

As soon as I add this line of code, the data I sent to the body of the request no longer gets passed as part of the request. Does this sound like behavior anyone else has experienced?

Comment: What if you set the header before setting the body?

Comment: Tried that, no dice. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you verified what's going on with a packet sniffer?

Comment: Have you managed to solve that?

Answer (score 3):

I am also using

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

Check this explanation
[What does "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean)