# Is the JSON too large to parse?

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I've fetch a list of schools with their corresponding columns from my database which has a 1000+ rows then convert it to JSON and pass it to my view and parse it using

```
$.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Model.subChoiceJsonString)')
```

then place it to  an array

```
ko.observableArray($.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Model.subChoiceJsonString)'));
```

but my problem is it does not work , but it works when there the number of rows are much smaller.

I'm thinking that it can't be parse due to a limitation of a string in Javascript. Is that correct? How can I make it work?

Comment: 'it does not work'? What is, and what is not working exactly? Any error message?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you receive an error? Is the page too slow to load? Do you get a long running script message in the browser?

Comment: Look at the generated source.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: it could also be a certain record, possibly containing some offending characters. Your server should send the appropriate character encoding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9254891/511795

Comment: @Baszz,Andrew it does not display  when i display the values ob the array in the table using foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah that seems like it would be huge... Instead, I would add pagination or something similar to your control.  I don't know why a user would want to see 1000+ items at once anyways.  Instead, only display 50-100 at a time and allow the user to paginate through the full list.

Comment: JSON.parse should have no trouble parsing that.

Comment: i've used 80,000 row DB table exports in JSON (15mb total footprint); takes about half a sec to parse, but works just fine and instantly after that.

Answer (score 6):

`parseJSON()` takes a string.
You're passing it an incorrectly-escaped string literal, which will break if the JSON has single quotes.

Instead, you should use a regular Javascript literal:

```
var myObject = @Html.Raw(Model.subChoiceJsonString);
```

Note that this will break if the JSON has U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR; see [here](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset).

Answer (score 0):

There are no size limits in HTTP itself, but maybe your server framework imposes some limit. Or maybe which larger responses your HTTP request times out.