# REST, PHP - Handling Client's POST Data Character Encoding

Tags: php, json, rest, character-encoding

In my RESTful service written in PHP, in order to update a resource, the client sends raw JSON via POST in the request content (not from a form, which means Content-Type: application/json)

How should I handle the request in order to prevent character encoding problems?

Should I convert the data sent by the client to UTF-8 before handling it, or should I just assume it's utf-8?

I'm asking this question since JSON can be encoded in different ways.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show a bit of code to clarify? I usually url-encode the JSON string, then send it up with the call as a parm.

Comment: I refer to the case in which the client(which isn't my code) surprises the server with JSON data with different encoding than UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you write your PHP code to assume all incoming JSON data is encoded as UTF-8, since that's the [default in the spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14955491/656069), and certainly the default in most JSON codecs.

It would be a good idea though to make it explicit in your API documentation that UTF-8 is assumed for `application/json` content. And if a client wants to transmit JSON encoded differently, instruct them to pass a different `Content-Type` header that specifies the non-default encoding, with a header like this: `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-16`.

Comment: Now after checking was made available to me: If the content sent is UTF-16BE(for example), the PHP string will contain it like a binary, so parsing json will fail anyway.

I wanted to take the charset from Content-Type and convert the data to UTF-8, but Symfony2 returns "json" from Request::getContentType(), so the charset wasn't available to me.