# OkHttp returning unreadable characters

Tags: android, okhttp

I am sending a request to server and getting [Collection + Json](http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/) in responce. Every thing is perfect in PostMan.

[image]

But when I am doing same things in code using OKHTTP, I am getting some unreadable characters.

[image]

Here is my code

```
      OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            requestBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("email", email)
                    .add("password", psd)
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.collection+json")
                    .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46cmVhbHNlYw==")
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();

            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
              String s = response.body().string();

                response.body().close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I tried some other url and those are working perfect.

many thanks.

Comment: [Check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean) and see if its properly implemented

Comment: Well this is for the Accept part.

Comment: [Check](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes)

Comment: okay I tried by adding this header too .addHeader("Content-type", "application/json") . and again no luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue and it wasn't very difficult one although I tried lot's of difficult approaches :P

I solved the issue by removing this line from the code

```
 .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
```

hope it help to some one other who got stuck like me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue while fetching available languages from a web API.
Adding UTF-8 encoding as header solved it for me:

```
.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8")
```

Maybe this helps someone.