# How do I convert json into a kotlin object in ktor using content negotiation?

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest, kotlin, ktor

I'm new to Ktor, and I'm trying to build a backend that processes login credentials. I'm attempting to use the content negotiation feature to convert JSON into a native Kotlin object, but I keep getting an unsupported media type exception. Here is my code:

```
fun Application.main() {
    install(CallLogging)
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        register(ContentType.Application.Json, GsonConverter())
    }
    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondHtml {
                head {
                    title("Kotlin Webapp")
                    script {
                        type = ScriptType.textJScript
                        src = "main.bundle.js"
                    }
                }
                body {
                    div {
                        id = "root"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        post("/login") {
            val credentials = call.receive<Credentials>()
            println(credentials)
        }
    }
}

data class Credentials(val username: String, val password: String)
```

And here is the incoming Json I am trying to convert, which I am sending via XMLHttpRequest:

```
{"username":"Jamdan2","password":"sometext"}
```

I have searched the web for answers, but could not find what I am doing wrong. Can anybody help?

Comment: Does the request have the correct content type?

Comment: That seems to have been my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, since my comment seems to have helped:

You need to be sure that the request's [`Content-Type` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) is set to the correct value, in this case, [`application/json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean), otherwise the server cannot be entirely sure what to do with the received content.

> In requests, (such as [`POST`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) or [`PUT`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT)), the client tells the server what type of data is actually sent.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```