# Creating a Trigger on an Oracle Schema to replace certain characters

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, ascii

I'm having issues with non ASCII characters getting into my database due to user input.

I want to create a trigger on the database so when a specific character is inserted/updated it just replaces it with a blank space.

This is my trigger (I will add multiple characters that are not allowed) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER database.incidents_ascci_summary  
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON database.table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        if :new.column like '%'||chr(253)||'%' then
           :new.column := REPLACE( :new.column, ''%'||chr(253)||'%'', ' ' );
END if;
END;
/
```

chr(253) = ý

Which creates the trigger. However, when I run

```
UPDATE table f
SET f.column = 'Hiýa' 
WHERE f.incidentid = 'INCIDENT#'
```

I get this error message from Oracle:

ORA-04098: trigger 'INCMAN.INCIDENTS_ASCCI_SUMMARY' is invalid and failed re-validation

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem with non-ASCII characters? We are in 2018!

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/json');   Using json to display information. It doesn't like non ASCII characters.

Comment: Maybe this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue in :

```
:new.column := REPLACE( :new.column, ''%'||chr(253)||'%'', ' ' );
```

It should be:

```
:new.column := REPLACE( :new.column, chr(253), ' ' );
```

Also, you don't need to check before using the `REPLACE`, but you can simply do

```
BEGIN
        :new.column := REPLACE( :new.column, chr(253), ' ' );
END;
```

If you need to handle more than one character, `TRANSLATE` could be a way; for example:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('aaXbbYccZdd', 'XYZ', '   ') from dual
```

gives:

```
TRANSLATE('AAXBBYCCZDD','XYZ','')
---------------------------------
aa bb cc dd
```

Comment: Thank you Aleks! Worked like a dream.