# When sending POST request to backend API via fetch(), the body has only key and no value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch

When I'm sending a POST request to my backend express server, the `req.body` contains only the key part where the entire body is the key and the value part is empty

This is the frontend fetch request

```
let data = {
  videoUrl: "dummy text"
}
fetch("/api/getinfo", {
  method:"POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

This is how I handle it in backend (**NOTE**: I'm using `body-parser`)

```
app.post("/api/getinfo", (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

I expect the output to be

```
'{ "videoUrl":"dummy text" }'
```

But what I get is

```
{ '{"videoUrl":"dummy text"}': '' }
```

The entire requests body is the key, and the value is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed an issue in your *header*;

```
fetch("/api/getinfo", {
  method:"POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" //this very line
  },
```

I guess what you meant is

```
fetch("/api/getinfo", {
  method:"POST",
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  },
```

**Note**: Your header denotes what the content is encoded in. It is not necessarily possible to deduce the type of the content from the content itself, i.e. you can't necessarily just look at the content and know what to do with it. So you need to be sure of what you're writing in your header else you will end up with an error.

I will suggest you get to read more about [What does “Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8” really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean)

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong Content-Type to send json

Try

```
"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

Comment: I tried using the above solution. Now req.body is just empty.

Comment: Make sure using json body parser

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are stringifying the data:

`body: JSON.stringify(data)`

should be

`body: data`

That should fix it