# Which Mime Types contain charset=utf-8 directive?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mime-types, deno

To make it easy to visualize, below is the following Record lookup table.

I just can't seem to find anywhere online where it tells you which of these are supposed to also contain `charset=utf-8`.

Should I just assume it's anything similar to text?

Take a look:

```
const MEDIA_TYPES: Record<string, string> = {
  ".md": "text/markdown",
  ".html": "text/html",
  ".htm": "text/html",
  ".json": "application/json",
  ".map": "application/json",
  ".txt": "text/plain",
  ".ts": "text/typescript",
  ".tsx": "text/tsx",
  ".js": "application/javascript",
  ".jsx": "text/jsx",
  ".gz": "application/gzip",
  ".css": "text/css",
  ".wasm": "application/wasm",
  ".mjs": "application/javascript",
  ".otf": "font/otf",
  ".ttf": "font/ttf",
  ".woff": "font/woff",
  ".woff2": "font/woff2",
  ".conf": "text/plain",
  ".list": "text/plain",
  ".log": "text/plain",
  ".ini": "text/plain",
  ".vtt": "text/vtt",
  ".yaml": "text/yaml",
  ".yml": "text/yaml",
  ".mid": "audio/midi",
  ".midi": "audio/midi",
  ".mp3": "audio/mp3",
  ".mp4a": "audio/mp4",
  ".m4a": "audio/mp4",
  ".ogg": "audio/ogg",
  ".spx": "audio/ogg",
  ".opus": "audio/ogg",
  ".wav": "audio/wav",
  ".webm": "audio/webm",
  ".aac": "audio/x-aac",
  ".flac": "audio/x-flac",
  ".mp4": "video/mp4",
  ".mp4v": "video/mp4",
  ".mkv": "video/x-matroska",
  ".mov": "video/quicktime",
  ".svg": "image/svg+xml",
  ".avif": "image/avif",
  ".bmp": "image/bmp",
  ".gif": "image/gif",
  ".heic": "image/heic",
  ".heif": "image/heif",
  ".jpeg": "image/jpeg",
  ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
  ".png": "image/png",
  ".tiff": "image/tiff",
  ".psd": "image/vnd.adobe.photoshop",
  ".ico": "image/vnd.microsoft.icon",
  ".webp": "image/webp",
  ".es": "application/ecmascript",
  ".epub": "application/epub+zip",
  ".jar": "application/java-archive",
  ".war": "application/java-archive",
  ".webmanifest": "application/manifest+json",
  ".doc": "application/msword",
  ".dot": "application/msword",
  ".docx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
  ".dotx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template",
  ".cjs": "application/node",
  ".bin": "application/octet-stream",
  ".pkg": "application/octet-stream",
  ".dump": "application/octet-stream",
  ".exe": "application/octet-stream",
  ".deploy": "application/octet-stream",
  ".img": "application/octet-stream",
  ".msi": "application/octet-stream",
  ".pdf": "application/pdf",
  ".pgp": "application/pgp-encrypted",
  ".asc": "application/pgp-signature",
  ".sig": "application/pgp-signature",
  ".ai": "application/postscript",
  ".eps": "application/postscript",
  ".ps": "application/postscript",
  ".rdf": "application/rdf+xml",
  ".rss": "application/rss+xml",
  ".rtf": "application/rtf",
  ".apk": "application/vnd.android.package-archive",
  ".key": "application/vnd.apple.keynote",
  ".numbers": "application/vnd.apple.keynote",
  ".pages": "application/vnd.apple.pages",
  ".geo": "application/vnd.dynageo",
  ".gdoc": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
  ".gslides": "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation",
  ".gsheet": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
  ".kml": "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml",
  ".mkz": "application/vnd.google-earth.kmz",
  ".icc": "application/vnd.iccprofile",
  ".icm": "application/vnd.iccprofile",
  ".xls": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
  ".xlsx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
  ".xlm": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
  ".ppt": "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
  ".pot": "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
  ".pptx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
  ".potx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template",
  ".xps": "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument",
  ".odc": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart",
  ".odb": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database",
  ".odf": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula",
  ".odg": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics",
  ".odp": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
  ".ods": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
  ".odt": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
  ".rar": "application/vnd.rar",
  ".unityweb": "application/vnd.unity",
  ".dmg": "application/x-apple-diskimage",
  ".bz": "application/x-bzip",
  ".crx": "application/x-chrome-extension",
  ".deb": "application/x-debian-package",
  ".php": "application/x-httpd-php",
  ".iso": "application/x-iso9660-image",
  ".sh": "application/x-sh",
  ".sql": "application/x-sql",
  ".srt": "application/x-subrip",
  ".xml": "application/xml",
  ".zip": "application/zip",
};

/** Returns the content-type based on the extension of a path. */
function contentType(pathname: string): string | undefined {
  return MEDIA_TYPES[pathname];
}

console.log(contentType("/dashboard/v1/index.html"));
console.log(contentType("/dashboard/v1/logo.svg"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*are supposed to also contain `charset=utf-8`*"? The charset (encoding) does not depend on, and cannot be derived from, the file extension.

Comment: I meant which "known file extensions" whose content type can usually be predicted provided someone isn't just mislabeling file extensions for the fun of it.

Comment: No, I meant what I said: you cannot predict the charset from the file extension. A `.html` file should have html content (unless mislabelled), but you can't tell from the file extension whether that html content is encoded as UTF-8 or something else.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh. I see your point. Perhaps determine it based on http header `'Content-Language': 'en-US',`. Hmmm. Excellent point.

Comment: I doesn't depend on the language either. What exactly is your use case, what do you need this for?

Comment: A static file server. And right again. Language isn't ultimately ideal.

Comment: So you read the files from disk and serve them via HTTP, and want to add the appropriate content-type header? Ok. Who stores the files on the disk, and what encoding do they use for text files?

Comment: The user stores files on the disk. The encoding they use is... Oh. I see what you did there. The idea is, you can run this script and serve a directory with sub-directories as a file server.

Comment: Actually I wanted you to answer "*they always use utf-8 because that's the best practice*" :-) (If that were the case, you could and should just hardcode that value). But if they don't, yes, you're in trouble. You can try a heuristic (see e.g. https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-is-character-encoding-auto-detection, https://superuser.com/questions/301552/how-to-auto-detect-text-file-encoding) but it won't work 100% of the time. I'd rather recommend to omit the `charset` parameter altogether if you don't know, and let the browser handle it.

Comment: And to allow the browser to handle it, I must NOT use http header `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`, correct?

Comment: I think since you *are* providing a content-type (just one without a charset), it wouldn't be sniffed anyway. Encoding autodetection is something separate I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MDN Says:

> For example, for any MIME type whose main type is text, you can add the optional charset parameter to specify the character set used for the characters in the data. If no charset is specified, the default is ASCII (US-ASCII) unless overridden by the user agent's settings. To specify a UTF-8 text file, the MIME type text/plain;charset=UTF-8 is used.

So, for anything based on `text/...` you can optionally add the charset.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#structure_of_a_mime_type

The following update to `contentType()` function demonstrates one solution.

```
/** Returns the content-type based on the extension of a path. */
function contentType(ext: string): string | undefined {

  const charsetUtf8 = "; charset=UTF-8";

  // Content types that do not start with text/.. but usually contain charset=utf-8
  const specialCase = [
    "application/json",
    "application/xml",
    "application/rss+xml",
  ];

  let outputContentType = MEDIA_TYPES[ext];

  // Return undefined.
  if(!outputContentType) return;

  if(outputContentType.startsWith("text/") || specialCase.includes(outputContentType)) {

    // Combine Content-Type with charset=utf-8
    outputContentType = outputContentType + charsetUtf8;

  // Return combined.
    return outputContentType;

  } else {
    // Return for any other types or undefined.
    return outputContentType;
  }
  
}
```

Then theoretically, you could return a `422: Unprocessable Entity` on any content type NOT present in the mime type list.

```
let requestedFilePath = path.join("./", context.main.http.server.root, urlPathNameParsed.dir, urlPathNameParsed.base);

try {
  // try as file...
  const file = await Deno.readFile(requestedFilePath);

  // If file extension is not on media list...
  if(typeof(contentType(urlPathNameParsed.ext)) === 'undefined') { 

    // Set Content-Type header for this response
    responseHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');

    await e.respondWith(
      new Response("HTTP 422: Unprocessable Entity", {
        headers: responseHeaders,
        status: 422,
        statusText: 'Unprocessable Entity',
      })
    );

  } else {

    // Set Content-Type header for this response
    responseHeaders.set('Content-Type', `${contentType(urlPathNameParsed.ext)}`);

    // Build and send the response
    await e.respondWith(
      new Response(file, {
        headers: responseHeaders, 
        status: 200, 
        statusText: 'OK'
      })
    );

  }
```

Comment: THAT, clarifies it. So much easier. Thank you!

Comment: Although... `application/json` usually contains it too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean/9254967

Comment: Not sure how to reformulate this, but that doesn't mean that **only** the ones that start with `text/` may need this. As Op already stated a few `application/` like `application/json` or `application/ecmascript` and `application/xml`, along with `image/svg+xml` and maybe others I'm not aware of or don't remember. The rule of thumb is then more "anything that is consumed as text". Also to be noted that some UAs (looking at you Safari) do choke on the presence of the `charset` header in some cases (like when generating an svg Blob and trying to display it).

Comment: Note that `application/json` should not contain the `charset` type. When decoding json, you need to follow the steps inside the JSON standard for automatic charset detection of he small list of allowed types