# windows active directory using LDAP - thumbnail photo can not convert to jpeg image

Tags: javascript, node.js, active-directory

I am trying to retrieve thumbnailPhoto from Windows Active Directory using LDAP. I am getting below value for thumbnailPhoto field however I can not derive the base64 value which will convert to an image.

```html
  thumbnailPhoto: '����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000��\u0000C\u0000\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0004\u0004\u0004\u0004\u0005\u0005\u0005\u0005\u0005\u0007\u0007\u0006\u0006\u0007\u0007\u000b\b\t\b\t\b\u000b\u0011\u000b\f\u000b\u000b\f\u000b\u0011\u000f\u0012\u000f\u000e\u000f\u0012\u000f\u001b\u0015\u0013\u0013\u0015\u001b\u001f\u001a\u0019\u001a\u001f&""&0-0>>T��\u0000C\u0001\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0004\u0004\u0004\u0004\u0005\u0005\u0005\u0005\u0005\u0007\u0007\u0006\u0006\u0007\u0007\u000b\b\t\b\t\b\u000b\u0011\u000b\f\u000b\u000b\f\u000b\u0011\u000f\u0012\u000f\u000e\u000f\u0012\u000f\u001b\u0015\u0013\u0013\u0015\u001b\u001f\u001a\u0019\u001a\u001f&""&0-0>>T��\u0000\u0011\b\u0000d\u0000�\u0003\u0001"\u0000\u0002\u0011\u0001\u0003\u0011\u0001��\u0000\u001d\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0003\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0005\u0006\u0003\u0004\u0007\u0002\b\t\u0001\u0000��\u0000\b\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�9K$\t\u0012�P��7"\\K-�\u001f�|��]���3�y�7\n' +
    'ڳ<�ѫ��\u0013\u0017W����<�Y+b��Gx����\\\u000eW�śsX�Q������_�%����I;�K\u0005�h2*"�K!�o��p�\u00181f����:�fS�y����_e�[\u0007�,\'\u0006�\u0004��m���M�b*U\\\u001b�ϓy�F�m\f`\u0004��+i�\u0006G4����\u0014�tk�TגZ4=-���d��\t�o�\u0000P\u0010�\u0012 �K���.\u000b�IiڋҝQ!I-i��f\u0019͞��\u0016���\u000fW8P\u001a�M�S`ku��ܺ-�H\u001e��q@����\u0000\u001b\u0001\u0000\u0002\u0003\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\u0005\u0002\u0003\u0006\u0007\u0001\u0000��\u0000\n' +
    '\u0002\u0002\u0010\u0003\u0010\u0000\u0000\u0000��Cf������,��x}]�٤j���u\r!�\u0001K���Gv\\�>�)�\fd�%A\u0000��~%�\\�\u0016\r�\u0014M�傱\\����PrX�\u001b &-J�n����J�M]�}�Ӳ�!���w�:6U�\u0019I\u0014ir\u0014�Wf�͡����\u0000"\u0010\u0000\u0002\u0003\u0001\u0000\u0002\u0003\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0003\u0000\u0001\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0012\u0011\u0013\u0014\u0015!\u00071��\u0000\b\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0005\u0001]\u0014����C\u0007H�\u0017�\u0006�O�w\u0015�\u0006@�md_\u000bIL�#\b�j�Vy����X�c��~Yye\u0003�\u000eS��W\u0015�a�q�/���pf�˝C\u0016\u0003P>�D����42��P�\u0011�P\\�Ե]OH\u0018��qX\u0016\u0016+�I\\^K��˸��\u0013��W�POTA���Ń.�~ ��\u0010��r�\u001dU�\b\u0019��P��e\u0013��сj�`\u0012�ܧ\u0014�\n' +
    "\u000bn���+D�������\u0000R��4W×U\u000bү\u000f�\u0007����;�n�Ac\u0012�\u001d��D�\u0015ݜ���\\�g�?E��S�\u0000\u0012�{�t���\u001fJ���룫�A_�C�x�\u0000�y\u000eF\u0007�\u0016�|�'��e3�\u000b]\foE�C�лwkS%�:#��d;�%\u000fBQ\u000f�\n" +
    '�\u001d}\f��ݪ��6\u000e���6w>�\u0019�L�kH�*�&ڄ�y^U����3&\u0007k��=\u0001�W8=Ǚ��C?7���F�z��;�m}F}���KwD�i�e4>���\u001a��\u0002�&v\u0015x�>;�?\t\tcW�� �R�)��(�|�\u0000��\u001d��M�~��i�#��/9AG�\u0000Oi\u0015��rΆ�v����0�\u001fPJw`l�9�J�DV*+n|ʤ���2��K�U2�]��?���[V\u0010���2�t\u001f\u0014Ewf\u001e�=P^]\u001dv�������_(��w���[�D��\\o�yc� Q����Y�.���;�S<g����u�\u001d�ڽ��b�eB�E\u0014<�U�Q\u0019���\u0013k��Yo���I�y\u0005�W�j���j�t\u00010���G�]-\u0017���Idv�Q\u001a��/�А�\u0010+т���:r�8\t�ϓ W]K\u001dݺ&���V$3T��\u0016ힶ\u0014&,�Mi\u0016j%vLE5��\u0016�\u000f_��Y{^�Օ�4�\'�I�y���A�աU��Sԥ\u0001�H}\u0018����{D��\u001cH{0�+�\u0002\u0004��^M\u001b\u001f3�jM\u001a]�\u001f\u0015�+>\\��ina�f��g��\u00008\u0010\u0000\u0001\u0003\u0002\u0003\u0005\u0005\u0007\u0003\u0003\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0002\u0011\u0003!\u0012"1\u0004\u0013Aa�#2BQq\u0010br���� 3R\u00050�4Cc����\u0000\b\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0006?\u0001�k+��%~�Y)ǭՉ\u001e�f.(j\u0015�)2J��&V�h��\u001a�n�5�ܬ\u0017uwJ�О~�\u001e�\u0016���h�8,����\u0012��x\u000bUf9Z���Y�.*��&�p\\=�!p+@�-^�h�Oi�;�L�\u001e�jP�Z�]�\u001c\u0006=�\u001bK�\u0003\u001a(¹+\u0005o�\u0006:�\u001a��.\u0000��B\u001f�_�ΆQ��A�O\u000f$\u001d��\u0001�0�J�M&�q.�{XF���X�;���f\u0011�N�\u0014Uؙ��2A�\u0000�����٧Kxw�4\u00105�<\u0013^Ƈ��Z��\u0011�~��P�=����D�٩��\\G�Wb�4�����bv�S�\u001f%m��3<a\u001c[eR\u000f\u0000�N�]�w\u001b�ʆ\\�Z�e���i�@J7�ԧ_Ԩ\ruK��r���J�\u000bv�\n' +
    'n�-[6�O\t�@@c�\f�u�v��ك\u000f����<\u0016\u001aB�I\u001f�2>�\u001cB8Bԕ�[�㍄]8Qa\u001dS��cÂ&2��\\�\u0006#NI����(\u0007��\n' +
    "&\u0002-n�\r�<ƫ��'\t�\n" +
    '��R��U��B\u0000��!�V\u0010��\\u���c��Ln�D>\t���\u001bZ=\n' +
    '�_j�P�f>K\u0012���O%�q"��t[�ΰ�0�k`\r!\u0018=Q.0\u0014^>�x�Zj��53�\u000f$��{��sV�Q�D�\f#ـ\u0011.��\u0014��Qd\f.�\u001eJ��\u001d�cw1�Bl=\u0011��a�c�@>9��\u0004CD��?�\'\u0006\'\u000e�5�\u001d\u0006�>\u001fF���|E\\i�i\u0001k�5�\u0006�\b�]s)�\u0003\u001c�kIM�9�\u0002\u0016\fxg�5�%ׄئj\u0013�\u0011?T\u001b��r`\u0006�u�N�$\u001e���{�T��ne�\u001b�Ӏ��4�]$�\u001a͙͜��\u001c$t\t�,�.97n��tw�\u0013�\f�uFL��`m\u0017�\r��\t�q\u0018���E�\\����:���A�}�uIdh�b��xZ��n7=�r�CL@�E\u001dϼ��S��S;كD���h\u00171���\u0001�p��T�\u00119pG�o�V�\u001d w�z�<óe7����\r�\u001a��oTp\u001e�oP�/�B\u0002�WU�X\u0018\u0007�\u0003V�\u000b8��\u0002~D�l���CN\u0018�\u0018R���\'n�ϺS�{3�sx�t]�g�p\u0013���+�8�\u001cj\u0011?�\n' +
    'Y�\u00073Y\u0001�5\u000e����\u0019��&n�[��l�Sk�\u0015\fj^0��\t������Ñ���\u0007\u0017N��B��ݨ\',�MݬxGtz����U�ˣ\u0002�S�b5\u0019[�B�����R5^<S����h\u0005�C��3h1\u0006c�֦��u\b��\u0018G�Ŷ�ĳM/���Q�<�4�0`�".�\u0015\u001cLjnV\n' +
    '�0�S@m� �ڝ�\u0006�\u0010�� \u0006Ќ1�\\��L:�\u000e�=�^M�Qis��A��\t��8t���s���:)�������H�$sT�C�M�۽�l�6��I���;�\u001dUj\u0018�\u0000��>#�\u0000�ݫ�\u0001�LE�]%��������\u0000%\u0010\u0001\u0000\u0003\u0000\u0002\u0002\u0003\u0001\u0000\u0002\u0003\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0011!1AQaq�����\u0010�����\u0000\b\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0001?\u0010�8�fU����մ\u0007\u001fM\u0010\u0015\u0012�Q���C\u0007���\u0007�\b���\u0000\u001c�1f��t\u0017�W�Pq/��\u001c�\u0003�\u0017VJ T�\u0003C5�����\u0000�_�\u0001r"�eps�?@\u001f2�Prz1f��c̝$U�A�\u0012�<�\u000f,,��\u001e��0~�\u0006<��\u000fI\f\b��\u0003�O�j���\u0000½��\u00056�C��\u0006��"]C\r�\u0013\\\u001d\u001d�E\u001d�\b֊mX�D�s�\b�� >I��5�_�\\\u001a49��\u0004\\���[\u0014���\u000b\u0001<�Pv���/�\u0016U-\u0011\rq\u0018��\f\\�jp$\u001e�R\u0000|���\u0011oy`0��\u001d��\b拜YP��M�p\u0007`O���:\r? �\u0004�\u0012�NGd\u0001QО�l�\u0000ħ.��D\u0014���6CJ�d\u0017B��\f�h�o�$N���n�����$��\u0005#\u0003ߍ\n' +
    'c����\bB��ja�Ћ����q�\n' +
    '��\u0001�Y��)Jk�UC��\u0011G����� @?\u0000M�L���K��:Ji��<\u0002�8E\u000bQ!_�<\r;\t�\u000e��\bU\u0005)ܿ\n' +
    '�1����T�J�H�W���**0_��z\n' +
    "@7���@���[6j�US�;�GB���EG�\u001aј:%'�\u0006��\u0012�h\u0000p%>�5U��,\n" +
    '\u001bm\u001f�W����v��\f\u0001xQ���\u0001\u001b��\u0011?�\u0013�� �Z\u0015������5Y\b\u0014�\u0000]�x\u000b�݈L�\t�ki�\u0018;|@��n�\u0000�H���R�\u0001�\u0012�j�=��\u001b5.T�\u0002�Ә���P�����\\G\u0004�\u0001��|�0�./\b켿L\u000f��hD�:��v�s�xR���<z�o��T\u0000��D�An�9�\u0005v|\r\u000b勅\u001b�y\u0017�(�*�lm�"�%��&�j��*\u0019�]9�i`B�\u001b�x�1��3j�^\u0014`@��\u0011��� ���N�j�\u001e����Y�B��\f?�[*�F5���JJ c�x>\b!>\u0000\u0017�Ȋ�H��)�$����;�F�A`��|\n' +
    '\u0004\u0007�\u0012����ӲTYE{��_�ʪ�c�����\u0019յ��\u0004��\u0007\u001e\u0007�4����8�mL�\u001f\u0012Tv�\b��\u0002O����01���)Z\u0005�\'�Ƞ��K8�/EǴ���#Q\u0006��8�\r0\ttў�j\u0012��@h��q���;m`MH[���ݐR�[a�����u\\\u0013g��~\u0002Z��+�\u0006\u0016=�F��v�(�\u001c7п�E#M�\u0013�#��X;K>ۥ\u000bz\u0000E�sAN�\u000eKUZe.x�4�3�8[\u0014P�ie\b@�\u0003��~ey����\u0012\u0010\u001b\u0010���\u0003[%-/����\u0004n����m驂�w㻢3g\u0017��>��\u0001�\\�\u0006����;@�i?��O\u0001U.�L�Y��is�ݿ�"�855H�x��kU\'q+��z\u0000����h���L�D\u001d\u0018pS�\u0010\u0006�VKz�����\bX�\u001c�\\=��4\u001b�m�ȋ��Qž\u000fq<���H�dz�\n' +
```

This is how I tried in Node JS

```
const base64 = new Buffer(user.thumbnailPhoto, 'binary').toString('base64');
console.log("base64", base64);
```

I then copied this base64 to an online image converter but no success. Can any one guide me what am I missing here.

Also the typeof for thumbnailPhoto is string.

I get the below value for base64

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

Answer (score 0):

I want to mention these 2 observations straight away:

1. Usage of `new Buffer(string[,encoding])` is [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#new-bufferstring-encoding).
2. The http response in which you are getting the thumbnail photo might have the `Content-Type` header set as 'utf-8'(or something incorrect, as you are expecting data encoded in latin1/binary) which is creating an issue in encoding/decoding and subsequently while creating a blob, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean) for more info

Comment: the problem was that ldap-authentication library was converting the Buffer to string and I was not able to get a valid base64

Comment: @j10 Hi, i had similar problem, did you solve it?

Comment: @ЕгорСоловьев : I made a small patch in the library itself. I just posted an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

in node_modules/ldap-authentication/index.js I created patch

```
@@ -84,7 +84,12 @@ async function _searchUser(
               return
             }
             res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
    -          user = entry.object
    +          user = entry.object;
    +          const field = entry.attributes.find(attribute => attribute.type === "thumbnailPhoto");
    +          if(field) {
    +            const thumbnailPhotoBase64 = Buffer.from(field._vals[0], "utf-8").toString("base64");
    +            user.thumbnailPhoto = thumbnailPhotoBase64;
    +          }
             })
```

and in the app : `Buffer.from(user.thumbnailPhoto, "base64")`