# Adding encode header for REST framework

Tags: python, django

I am using `Django REST framework`

It returns `Content-Type: application/json` in header.

Normally it works, but some browser needs the precise header such as

`Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

How can I do this ??

I just return the `Response` here where should I set the header??

```
class SmartTagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Mood.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SmartTagSerializer
    def list(self,request,*args,**kwargs):

        objs = SmartTag.objects.all()
        custom_data = {
            'items': SmartTagSerializer(objs, many=True).data
        }
        custom_data.update({
            'meta':{"api":"SmartTag"}
        })
        return Response(custom_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django REST Framework [**`Response()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#response-objects) you can pass headers as argument

```
class SmartTagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Mood.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SmartTagSerializer
    def list(self,request,*args,**kwargs):

        objs = SmartTag.objects.all()
        custom_data = {
            'items': SmartTagSerializer(objs, many=True).data
        }
        custom_data.update({
            'meta':{"api":"SmartTag"}
        })
        header = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
        return Response(custom_data, headers=header)
```

If still facing some error I'll suggest you to read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254967/14457833)