# Response contains a JSON object | AssertionError: expected 'text/html; charset=utf-8' to include 'application/json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently trying to get my code that I am writing for a software engineering boot camp to pass the test suite on postman. Everything worked fine before I changed my .eslintrc.js file, as well as changing the package.json file devDependencies.

essentially I removed:

```
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2"
```

from:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2",
    "prettier": "^3.1.0"
  }
```

Then I ran npm install, after the changes to my package.json was made. Now I get the same errors from almost every request that I run, whether It's a POST, PUT, DELETE, or GET request, they all return this error:

```
Response contains a JSON object | AssertionError: expected 'text/html; charset=utf-8' to include 'application/json'
```

Here is an example of one of my requests, so that you can see what I am doing, inside of one of my functions:

```
module.exports.createItem = (req, res, next) => {

  const { name, weather, imageUrl } = req.body;

  ClothingItem.create({ name, weather, imageUrl, owner: req.user._id })
    .then((item) => {
      res.send({ data: item });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      if (e.name === "ValidationError") {
        const validationError = new Error(e.message);
        validationError.statusCode = HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
        next(validationError);
      }
      next(e);
    });
};
```

This is a POST request, and initially it does add the item, but when it tries to add an item with a "name" field less than 2 characters and a "name" field with greater than 30 characters, it then gives me the error above. Below I have added the code where I create parameters where the name field cannot be greater than 30 or less than 2. This was working before I changed my .eslintrc.js and package.json.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");
const user = require("./user");

const clothingItem = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: [30, "Name cannot be more than 30 characters"],
    minlength: [2, "Name cannot be less than 2 characters"],
  },
  weather: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["hot", "warm", "cold"],
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: (v) => validator.isURL(v),
      message: "Link is not valid",
    },
  },
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: user,
    required: true,
  },
  likes: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: user,
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("clothingItems", clothingItem);
```

If someone could help me with this issue then I would be most appreciative. This is my second post on Stack Overflow so I hope that I provided enough information. I am also relatively new to coding, so maybe the answer is obvious.

I'm not really sure how to go about this, and I looked up a few answers to try and find the problem and solve it before creating this post. I didn't find anything, and what I did find when I looked up this error, which is the title of the post this is what I found. [What does "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean)

Comment: What happens when you call `next(e)` instead of `res.send(someobject)` in your application? presumably, it continues on to an error handler that outputs html, and thus fails the test because it isn't json. I don't see what eslint has to do with this.

Comment: Are you positive that's the code that is running on this particular error? because i doubt it... given the server returned html

Comment: is anything sitting in front of the node server, like an apache nginx or iis reverse proxy, that could be swallowing errors?

Comment: @KevinB This is the error handler that it is passed to:                                                `const { HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR } = require("../utils/error");

module.exports = (error, req, res) => {
  res.status(error.statusCode || HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
    message: error.message,
  }); 
};`

Comment: @KevinB Also I believed that it was ,but now that you mention it, it is saying starting `node app.js` continually

Comment: I figured out the answer, it was because I didn't have next inside of my error handler that next(e) fires, and in turn it was returning those errors. Which I had removed this because Eslint was telling me that it was an error, since it was unused. I appreciate you taking time out of your day to assist with this issue though, thank you. @KevinB