# Checking for bad data in ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am getting sometimes bad `response data` or `undefined` or `null` or `empty string` as response. I am checking whether my response is of json before proceeding with further data manipulation.

```
function response(oResponse, xhr) {
    var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
    if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to check whether the `response` is `valid` before proceeding. I want to check for invalid responses like "null", "undefined", "emptry string" too along with checking whether the response is json before manipulating the data.

Comment: Okay, what's the problem?

Comment: I want to check for invalid responses like "null", "undefined", "emptry string" too along with checking whether the response is json before manipulating the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662620/best-way-to-find-out-if-response-is-json-during-ajaxsuccess --> this has a good way of going about it. I think the second part to your question could be answered by checking if the responseText is empty (or if the responseHeader attribute that you're looking for is empty/null/etc) -- ex: !xhr.responseText

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the snippet below

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// ...
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
  var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  if(response && typeof response === "object" && response !== null){
    // you're getting data in JSON
  }
}
```